# Turning Technologies RF receiver

Tags: hardware, decryption, security

At my university we're required to purchase these [RF clickers with an lcd screen](http://www.turningtechnologies.com/response-solutions/responsecard-rf-lcd) so professors who choose to take attendance can do so in an automated fashion, and occasionally administer simple quizzes without having to take time to grade them. The clicker costs about $50, so I thought, why not buy a receiver and write some code to interface with it and do cool things if I've already got half the hardware?

Research turned up [the receiver unit](http://www.turningtechnologies.com/receivers/rf-receiver) with no price listed, but some quick amazon and ebay checks revealed the going rate to be about $400 which is well outside the range that I as a student am willing to spend to hack on some hardware, no matter how cool.

Is there an alternate generic receiver module I could look into, something in the $10-$30 range? Is the signal employed by this particular clicker encrypted so I cannot access it anyway? $50 on the clicker is a fortune to spend as a student on a piece of technology that will essentially turn into a brick once I graduate.

Are there any resources out there that can provide any information on the signal and how I could extract meaningful data? I'm looking to be able to read clicker ID and responses, and hack together a controller for my laptop or a simple voting system I can use with my friends to mediate movie choices and meal debates.

Comment: Unable to create new tags presently but I feel 'signal analysis' would be an apt tag for this question.

Comment: There appears to be DIY Arduino receiver option out there: https://github.com/nickmooney/turning-clicker/blob/master/clicker_receive.ino

Answer (score 3):

You can build your own USB RF receiver fairly cheaply, for example:

http://hackaday.com/2012/03/20/software-defined-radio-from-a-usb-tv-capture-card/

This might be a good starting point, run the usb receiver, sniff the RF, press some buttons and see what happens :)

Comment: Admittedly I don't see the frequency range the clicker uses, maybe if you can find a manual online for the receiver?

Comment: Any chance for a pre-assembled unit? I'm not great with circuitry and don't have the proper tools at school

Comment: Addendum: I looked for a manual and can't seem to locate one with any sort of tech specs, seems they've got their tech locked down

Comment: Regarding the frequency, see http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/2985/1562

Comment: Found the frequency! 2401.0 - 2482.0 MHz, great tip @JasonGeffner

Comment: RTLSDRs don't have that range, usually from ~50MHz to ~1.8Ghz, for more info on RTLSDRs see http://sdr.osmocom.org/trac/wiki/rtl-sdr